# Math.pow(X,Y) java

Tags: java, android, math, onclick, switch-statement

Im making a scientific calculator and i want to use the power function but it gives the wrong answer like when i enter lets say 2 as a first value and then 3 as a second it gives me 27 instead of 8 its frustrating  please help this is the code for the power button in the switch statement :
 Note that the first value is save as this before the switch statement

ok here is the full code

```
    package com.example.scienteficcalc;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        num =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.etnum);
        bsin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bsin);
        bcos=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bcos);
        btan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btan);
        bsec=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bsec);
        bcsc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bcsc);
        bcot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bcot);
        bln=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bln);
        blog=(Button)findViewById(R.id.blog);
        bpwr=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bpwr);
        broot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.broot);
        bmod=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bmod);
        one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        two=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        three=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
        four=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b4);
        five=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b5);
        six=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b6);
        seven=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b7);
        eight=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b8);
        nine=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b9);
        zero=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b0);
        equal=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bequal);
        clear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bc);



        bsin.setOnClickListener(this);
        bcos.setOnClickListener(this);
        btan.setOnClickListener(this);
        bsec.setOnClickListener(this);
        bcsc.setOnClickListener(this);
        bcot.setOnClickListener(this);
        bln.setOnClickListener(this);
        blog.setOnClickListener(this);
        bpwr.setOnClickListener(this);
        broot.setOnClickListener(this);
        bmod.setOnClickListener(this);

        //numbers

        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);
        three.setOnClickListener(this);
        four.setOnClickListener(this);
        five.setOnClickListener(this);
        six.setOnClickListener(this);
        seven.setOnClickListener(this);
        eight.setOnClickListener(this);
        nine.setOnClickListener(this);
        zero.setOnClickListener(this);
        equal.setOnClickListener(this);
        clear.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.equals(one))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+one.getText());
        if(v.equals(two))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+two.getText());
        if(v.equals(three))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+three.getText());
        if(v.equals(four))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+four.getText());
        if(v.equals(five))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+five.getText());
        if(v.equals(six))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+six.getText());
        if(v.equals(seven))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+seven.getText());
        if(v.equals(eight))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+eight.getText());
        if(v.equals(nine))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+nine.getText());
        if(v.equals(zero))
            num.setText(num.getText()+""+zero.getText());
        /*if(v.equals(clear))
            num.setText("0");*/

        input = Double.valueOf(num.getText().toString());

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.bsin:



            output= Math.sin(input);
            answer=String.valueOf(output);

            num.setText(answer);

            break;
        case R.id.bcos:


            output= Math.cos(input);
            answer=String.valueOf(output);

            num.setText(answer);
            break;

        case R.id.btan:

            output= Math.tan(input);
            answer=String.valueOf(output);

            num.setText(answer);
            break;
        case R.id.bcsc:



            output= 1/Math.sin(input);

            answer=String.valueOf(output);

            num.setText(answer);
            break;
        case R.id.bsec:



            output= 1/Math.cos(input);

            answer=String.valueOf(output);

            num.setText(answer);
            break;
        case R.id.bcot:


        output= 1/ Math.tan(input);
        answer=String.valueOf(output);

        num.setText(answer);
        break;
        case R.id.blog:

            output = Math.log(input);
            answer=String.valueOf(output);

            num.setText(answer);
            break;
        case R.id.bln:



            output = 2.30258*Math.log(input);
            answer=String.valueOf(output);

            num.setText(answer);
            break;
        case R.id.bpwr:


            num.setText("");

             equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    input2= Double.valueOf(num.getText().toString());
                    output = Math.pow(input, input2);

                    answer=String.valueOf(output);

             num.setText(answer);
                }
            });


             break;
        case R.id.broot:
            output= Math.sqrt(input);
            answer=String.valueOf(output);

             num.setText(answer);
             break;
        case R.id.bc:

            Intent intent = getIntent();
             finish();
             startActivity(intent);

            break;


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `Math.pow` can't fail. Could you print `input` and `input2` ?

Comment: You're computing 3^3 = 27, not 2^3 = 8 - 2 isn't being saved like you think it is.  Posting the surrounding code would help us show you why

Comment: @ZouZou i don't under stand what do you want me to do ??

Comment: Your input is assuming the value of input2. You should show up some more code. Or just have a look yourself that did you goofed up with input & input2.

Comment: @Mabulhuda : Before calling the pow(), could you please print the values of input and input2??? So that we can check whether correct values are being set as an input to the pow function.

Answer (score 4):

`Math.pow` can't fail.

I highly suspect that you copy/paste your code and if you take a look :

`input = Double.valueOf(num.getText().toString());`

`input2= Double.valueOf(num.getText().toString());`

You got the values from the **same** `editText`. So if `num` contains "`3`", you're computing `3^3`, which is equals to `27`.

Comment: yeah but when you click the pwr button the text changes to 0 so when you enter the second value it will be changed

Comment: It will be changed, but since you're saving `input` in a member variable, when you click "2", then "^", then "3", input gets set to 3 before you click "=".  The "2" is just not saved

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow(2,3)` should give you 8 :P Check your code once again. You might have made a mistake in reading the inputs from the wrong editText. Try to pring out `num.setText("input1 value: input1 + " - input2 value: " + input2)` and see if everything is right.

EDIT:
After reading your full code, your `input` var is being set everytime onClick is being called. You need something like 
`if(input == null)` 
  `input = Double.valueOf(num.getText().toString());`

and set `input = null` as soon as you dont need it anymore